# Почему при смене фрагмента в tabsview onPageScrollStateChanged вызывается 3 раза

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

У меня есть таб вью активити и в нем три фрамгента:
Код активити:
метод вызывается ествественно в он крейт:

```
private void init_slider() {
    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


     // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new TabsActionAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
     pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
     pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);


    tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                initializeData();
                *****Log.w("Initialize Data:","Download initialized");******
        }
    });
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

}
```

Обратите внимание на строку помеченную *** ***

и теперь на логи:

```
06-17 10:50:33.485 21936-21936/eatgid.com.restaurant W/Initialize Data: Download initialized
06-17 10:50:33.510 21936-21936/eatgid.com.restaurant W/Initialize Data:: Download initialized
06-17 10:50:33.759 21936-21936/eatgid.com.restaurant W/Initialize Data:: Download initialized
```

Это за один свайп или клик!!! я уже не говорю о том что метод лисенера onPageScrolled
вызывается раз 10 при одном свайпе! куда копать?

и еще на засыпку по той же теме с табами, я в них пока не силен но меня пугает надпись в логе при свайпе:

```
06-17 10:50:33.762 21936-21936/eatgid.com.restaurant W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tab3{ffc7800 #2 id=0x7f0c0054 android:switcher:2131492948:2} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
```

значит ли это что у меня где то косяк в коде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что в процессе смены страницы состояние скролла меняется 3 раза, все просто.

1. Страница прокручена (`SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`)
2. Страница доводится до конечного состояния после прокрутки пользователя (`SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`)
3. Страница прокручивается пользователем (`SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`)

Посмотреть, какое состояние за что отвечает можно [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)

Comment: гениально ? большое спасибо за ваш ответ!

стоило сделать
`if(state==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {`
                    `initializeData();`
                    `Log.w("Initialize Data:", "Download initialized");`
                 `}`
и все пошло как надо! вызывается один раз

Comment: Могли бы вы подсказать также, почему возникает следующее сообщение?

`FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tab3{ffc7800 #2 id=0x7f0c0054 android:switcher:2131492948:2} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2`

Comment: @JulianDelCampo, а это сообщение вызывает какие-либо проблемы?

Comment: вообще видимых проблем вроде как не вызывает, но просто предчувствие такое что как будто что то все таки не так... я обычно очень серьезно отношусь к логам приложения, и даже какие то заурядные вещи типа Err(0) Log Buff или Service:ActiveConnections... мазолят глаза, что еще хуже, данные сообщения не гуглимы к сожелению